# nfs-kernel-server failed to start on debian

Tags: kubernetes, raspberry-pi, debian, cluster-computing, nfs

A bit new to this topic and would be great if one can provide some pointers in this case:
i have been trying to use NFS on an in-house built cluster. everything worked from the link i [followed](http://selkie-macalester.org/csinparallel/modules/RosieCluster/build/html/)  except common file sharing topic.

- installed NFS-kernel-server on master node
- installed NFS-common on slave / worker nodes
- configured /etc/exports on master node as required
- configured /etc/fstab properly on worker nodes with the mount location
- **But unable to start nfs-server on master node and the errors show issue with the dependencies**
- if needed i can provide output from journalctl -xe but main error shows "Failed to mount NFSD configuration filesystem."

Any pointer / solution would be greatly helpful.

**Output from journalctl -xe:**

> *The unit proc-fs-nfsd.mount has entered the 'failed' state with result 'exit-code'. Dec 13 10:06:39 ccc-001 systemd[1](http://selkie-macalester.org/csinparallel/modules/RosieCluster/build/html/): Failed to
>   mount NFSD configuration filesystem.
>   -- Subject: A start job for unit proc-fs-nfsd.mount has failed
>   -- Defined-By: systemd
>
> ### -- Support: https://www.debian.org/support
>
> ### -- A start job for unit proc-fs-nfsd.mount has finished with a failure.
>
> -- The job identifier is 1032 and the job result is failed. Dec 13 10:06:39 ccc-001 systemd[1](http://selkie-macalester.org/csinparallel/modules/RosieCluster/build/html/): Dependency failed for NFS Mount Daemon.
>   -- Subject: A start job for unit nfs-mountd.service has failed
>   -- Defined-By: systemd
>
> ### -- Support: https://www.debian.org/support
>
> ### -- A start job for unit nfs-mountd.service has finished with a failure.
>
> -- The job identifier is 1034 and the job result is dependency. Dec 13 10:06:39 ccc-001 systemd[1](http://selkie-macalester.org/csinparallel/modules/RosieCluster/build/html/): Dependency failed for NFS server and
>   services.
>   -- Subject: A start job for unit nfs-server.service has failed
>   -- Defined-By: systemd
>
> ### -- Support: https://www.debian.org/support
>
> ### -- A start job for unit nfs-server.service has finished with a failure.
>
> -- The job identifier is 1027 and the job result is dependency. Dec 13 10:06:39 ccc-001 systemd[1](http://selkie-macalester.org/csinparallel/modules/RosieCluster/build/html/): Dependency failed for NFSv4 ID-name
>   mapping service.
>   -- Subject: A start job for unit nfs-idmapd.service has failed
>   -- Defined-By: systemd
>
> ### -- Support: https://www.debian.org/support
>
> ### -- A start job for unit nfs-idmapd.service has finished with a failure.
>
> -- The job identifier is 1037 and the job result is dependency. Dec 13 10:06:39 ccc-001 systemd[1](http://selkie-macalester.org/csinparallel/modules/RosieCluster/build/html/): nfs-idmapd.service: Job
>   nfs-idmapd.service/start failed with result 'dependency'. Dec 13
>   10:06:39 ccc-001 systemd[1](http://selkie-macalester.org/csinparallel/modules/RosieCluster/build/html/): nfs-server.service: Job
>   nfs-server.service/start failed with result 'dependency'. Dec 13
>   10:06:39 ccc-001 systemd[1](http://selkie-macalester.org/csinparallel/modules/RosieCluster/build/html/): nfs-mountd.service: Job
>   nfs-mountd.service/start failed with result 'dependency'. Dec 13
>   10:06:39 ccc-001 systemd[1](http://selkie-macalester.org/csinparallel/modules/RosieCluster/build/html/): Condition check resulted in RPC security
>   service for NFS server being skipped.
>   -- Subject: A start job for unit rpc-svcgssd.service has finished successfully
>   -- Defined-By: systemd
>
> ### -- Support: https://www.debian.org/support
>
> ### -- A start job for unit rpc-svcgssd.service has finished successfully.
>
> -- The job identifier is 1042. Dec 13 10:06:39 ccc-001 systemd[1](http://selkie-macalester.org/csinparallel/modules/RosieCluster/build/html/): Condition check resulted in RPC security service for NFS client and
>   server being skipped.
>   -- Subject: A start job for unit rpc-gssd.service has finished successfully
>   -- Defined-By: systemd
>
> ### -- Support: https://www.debian.org/support
>
> ### -- A start job for unit rpc-gssd.service has finished successfully.
>
> -- The job identifier is 1041. Dec 13 10:06:39 ccc-001 sudo[4469]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root*

Comment: Did you ever solve this?